# Copy files in subfolders

Tags: unix

I have the following folder structure:

> ```
> Folder1       
> --FolderA    
>   --Gex_experiments     
> --FolderB     
>  --Gex_experiments     
> --FolderC    
>  --Gex_experiments    
> .......      
> --FolderAYCD
>  --Gex_experiments
> ```

In Folder1 a list of four .R scripts are present that I would like to copy in each Gex_experiments folder.

Can anyone help me please? 
I'm able to just copy such scripts in FolderA, FolderB, FolderC and FolderAYCD  but not in the subfolders Gex_experiments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a specific script to perform the copying? if so - do post it here. Otherwise I will advice you change working directory to perform the copying. Eg. cd Gex_experiments && cp some_files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within `Folder1`, you can do:

```
for i in */
do
    cp *.R "$i"Gex_experiments
done
```

Of course, this will copy *all* the `.R` files in `Folder1`. If there are some other `.R` files that you don't want to copy, you should make the `*.R` more specific.